# SSRS expression explanation in group list?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I'm working on SSRS reporting , we have one report in that group section is there and for 
one value named `Long-Only` some expression is there as follows

`=IIF(CDec(Parameters!NAV.Value) > 1,((SUM(Fields!LongMV.Value) - SUM(IIF(Right(Fields!SecurityType.Value, 4) = "Cash" OR Left(Fields!SecurityType.Value, 8) = "Treasury", Fields!LongMV.Value, 0)))/(Parameters!NAV.Value/1000)) -1,0)`

Here above expression is a calculation for `LONGVALUE`

I want to execute this function is there any way to do so (only this function by putting sample values)?

NAV.Value = 1200
SUM(Fields!LongMV.Value) = 49

what this does `(Right(Fields!SecurityType.Value, 4) = "Cash"`?

I'm new to ssrs reporting could anyone please help me to know the expression.

we are using stored procedures for reporting.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formatting it a bit helps:

```
=IIF
(
  CDec(Parameters!NAV.Value) > 1
  ,
  (
    (
      SUM(Fields!LongMV.Value) -
        SUM
        (
          IIF
          (
            Right(Fields!SecurityType.Value, 4) = "Cash" OR Left(Fields!SecurityType.Value, 8) = "Treasury"
            , Fields!LongMV.Value
            , 0
          )
        )
    ) /(Parameters!NAV.Value/1000)
  ) - 1
  , 0
)
```

So here we can see that for each group, the expression is calculating:

```
If NAV parameter > 1, return 0

Else return group level ((LongMV - Cash Long MV) / NAV parameter / 1000) - 1
```

Where `Cash Long MV` is:

`Group level Cash type Long MV + Group level Treasury type Long MV`.

So that's what the expression is calculating. I'm still not sure what the question is here - only you can put the above in any sort of context based on what your data all means.

Is this something you can discuss further with your colleagues?

**Edit after comment:**

`Right()` is just a standard SSRS/.NET function that returns a specified number of characters from the right of a string..

`Right(Fields!SecurityType.Value, 4) = "Cash"` checks whether certain Security Types should be included in the calculation, based on the last 4 characters in the Security Type value. This would include Security Types as *Settled Cash* and *Unsettled Cash*, for example.

For testing with specific values is to return those values to the Dataset in the stored procedure, e.g. Make it so that the total LongMV returned sums to your required value.

Or you could just hard code them into the formula; it's not really a question that has a definite answer.

Comment: I've answered your questions as best as I can. Where you've got many questions, it's probably most useful to create new ones instead of amending the original questions, although I suppose it depends on your perspective whether you think they are directly related or not. Anyway, I hope this helps.